# JSON retrieving and put value to a select box base on the data in JSON

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I have a JSON data from database and I want to put set the Select dropdown base on the data I retrieve on the JSON. Here are my codes below.

***jQuery***

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);
var inputs = "";
$.each(objJSON, function (i, v) {
    inputs += '<select class="form- " name="department[]"><option>選択してください</option><option>department one</option><option>industry two</option><option>industry three</option> <option>industry four</option></select>';
});
$("#input_container").html(inputs);
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="input_container"></div>
```

Below is my `console.log` output for my json.

[image]

How can I have an output just like below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why creating separate **< select >** to each option ?

why not generating **< option >** only  ?

```js
var objJSON = ['industry one', 'second industry', 'third ...']; //JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);


setTimeout(function(){ // timeout for DEMO only

  $('#DepartmentsDropDownList').empty();

  
  //if(isOptional || notRequiredInput)
  //  $('#DepartmentsDropDownList').append('<option value=""> -- Select an item</option>');
  
  for(var i in objJSON) {
      $('#DepartmentsDropDownList').append('<option value="'+ objJSON[i] +'">'+ objJSON[i] +'</option>');
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input_container">
  
  <select id="DepartmentsDropDownList" class="form-control" name="department[]">
    <option> -- Loading items...</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

---

**If you want separate select for each item**

```js
var objJSON = ['industry one', 'second industry', 'third ...']; //JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);


setTimeout(function(){ // timeout for DEMO only

  $('#inputs_container').empty();

  
  //if(isOptional || notRequiredInput)
  //  $('#DepartmentsDropDownList').append('<option value=""> -- Select an item</option>');
  
  for(var i in objJSON) {
      $('#inputs_container').append('<div> <select><option value="'+ objJSON[i] +'">'+ objJSON[i] +'</option></select> </div>');
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="inputs_container"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Selected certifications Solution**

---

```js
var objJSON = ['certification one', 'certification two', 'certification five']; //JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);
      $('#DepartmentsDropDownList').val(objJSON);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input_container">
  
  <select id="DepartmentsDropDownList" class="form-control" name="department[]" multiple="multiple" style="height: 100px;">
    <option value="certification one">certification one</option>
    <option value="certification two">certification two</option>
    <option value="certification three">certification three</option>
    <option value="certification four">certification four</option>
    <option value="certification five">certification five</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: I just get one empty dropdown sir.

Comment: the code snippet works fine, which solution not work with you ?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the json, I've posted above my JSON output sir. And the dropdown should have all option but select value base on the data in json.

Comment: I got it, see updated solution please (**Selected certifications Solution**)